# Trying to use colorsys to alter Hue/Sat. Returns greyscale images with weird coloured blocks

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I want to change an image's hue/saturation/brightness. Whether or not I actually alter the h/s/v parameters, the outputted image is always a greyscale version of the inputted image, with some blocky coloured sections. In this code example I have deliberately neglected to actually change the values so you can see a controlled example of the problem. Although there's a comment to explain where/when I intend to change hue.

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys
import numpy as np

image = Image.open("/home/some_image.jpg", mode="r")
width, height = image.size
np_image = np.asarray(image)
image.close()
np_image = np_image.reshape((height*width, 3))

out_image = np.zeros((height*width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
#out_image = np.zeros((height*width, 3))

for i in range(0, len(np_image)-1):
    hsv_tuple = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(np_image[i][0], np_image[i][1], np_image[i][2])
    h = hsv_tuple[0]
    # apply some transformations to the hue component...
    # h = h + yada yada yada
    rgb_tuple = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, hsv_tuple[1], hsv_tuple[2])
    rgb_tuple = np.asarray(rgb_tuple)
    out_image[i] = rgb_tuple

out_image = out_image.reshape((height, width, 3))

outim = Image.fromarray(out_image, "RGB")
outim.save("/home/some_recoloured_image.jpg")
```

Using this:

[image: input image]

I get this:

[image: output image]

Comment: Do you get the original image if you perform an identity transformation instead of your current transformations?

Comment: The input and output of the RGB/HSV functions in `colorsys` are floating point numbers. Could `dtype=np.uint8` for your input be the problem?

Comment: I think you're going to have to normalize the components of `np_image`.  IIRC they're integers between 0 and 255, so you'll need to divide them by 255.  (Or perhaps you're supposed to divide by 256, I've never been absolutely sure.)

Comment: @Jongware Thanks your answer sorted out the problem. Changing the 7th line from `np_image = np.asarray(image)` to  `np_image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32)` makes everything work perfectly.